# HTML form elements not properly aligned

Tags: html, css

After spending hours and hours I turned out to have this form and I just feel hopeless now...I can't figure out what to do or why the spaces are so messed-up and just lost...

http://jsfiddle.net/C7u9P/2/

I posted picture of what I am trying to make it look like and how it currently looks.... T_T

Any help on what to do or whats wrong is appreciated.
The Awesome Form:
[image: Perfect Form]

My form:
[image: my troublesome form]

Comment: I think that "the awesome form" used tables for alignment, or some other method, and thus using style kept all the fields aligned.
Do you have the source of "the awesome form" (its HTML/CSS code)?

Comment: @Jeff Hodge: /kinda offtopic. You should really consider dropping all those inline css stuff. Would be a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: Wow that is terrible xD lets see what I can make of it

Comment: I can access its source code but the source code for it is generated dynamically using java strus so there is more than just the source code..

Comment: @Eran the "Awesome Form"  would not *have to* be coded using tables for alignment.  It's actually standard to *not* use tables for formatting nowadays (unless, of course, you are representing tabular data)

Comment: And yet again we have tables for layout. Maybe out children will finally fix it when we have CSS X. Dont see any reason whatsoever this can't be acheived with pure CSS. Global Resets, No in-line styles and some creative design can do it.

Comment: Saw the HTML and all those inline styles and went NOPE! Get rid of all that inline CSS and the attributes like "align=left". It will be much simpler to set a stylesheet when the DOM elements can adhere to a global ruleset as opposed to having individual rules for each of them!

Comment: Can we have a clean copy of the code. Only the markup for the form plus the CSS for it that you have tried so far. Makes it near impossible to jumble through the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to recreate something it is better to start completely over at times. The generated code from java was certainly too complex to try and convert.

So heres a setup you could start out with:

http://jsfiddle.net/MwnSn/11/

I'll let you do the details yourself, the icons shouldn't be too hard and styling the inputs is possible too ofcourse. Be aware that I made use of the style normalization done by jsfiddle, I recommend using that stylesheet in your own work too. Only really tested in Chrome so you might want to check and debug IE, and it will probably break down when limited in width. Using the proper clearfix would also improve it a little. (overflow:auto to clear floats in that div.)

No tables.

Comment: yours is very pretty ! thanks a trillion id hug you if i was there :P looks so much nicer than mine :P, 1 question, Is it possible to write inside that div for description?

Comment: Sure, you can replace that div with controls of your own if you like I just put the div there as a representation of where the wysiwyg editor could be. But if you replace it make sure you apply the styles of the current div to the new elements to make it look right.